# Sent mail does not show mail trail with custom outlook message form

Tags: outlook-2010

I have created a Custom Outlook(Outlook 2010) form using default Mail message form, here i have separate Compose and Read page. The Compose page has TO, CC, Subject, Message and additional custom UI elements; Status(a dropdown box) and Ticket(Text Box) and Read page has Labels From, CC, Subject, Message, Status and Ticket. These custom elements are bind to user defined fields rStatus and rticket.

Assigned custom form in Actions tab for Reply, Reply to ALL, Forward and published in my own Inbox and sent folder

On Running following case

1. Open Custom form in New Items drop down
2. Set values in TO(with my own email id), Subject, Status, Ticket and some text in Message Body including the signature.
3. Send this custom message form
4. Open received message in Inbox, i can see from, subject, status, ticket and message body as sent in point 2 & 3.
5. Reply this message by changing Status, Ticket and append some more text in the message body in the top.
6. Send this custom message form
7. Open received message, here i can see from, subject, updated status and Ticket, **while the Message body is empty.**
8. If I open the message in sent folder after pt 6, **the message body is empty there as well.**

My form has no scripts and send form def with item is unchecked

Thanks

Kiran

Comment: Please tell language and some code, of you have already tried

Comment: There is no code its all UI, I just used existing mail message form, added new elements, bind them with user defined fields and published it with some settings.

Comment: And **how** did you do that? VBA? How did you do that binding?

Comment: Outlook with Developer extension, one can open existing form(in this case mail message form) in design mode. In design mode it has control tool box, one needs to drop a control and bind an existing mail field(like to, cc etc) or create a new once.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug that was solved in latest patches for microsoft, after updating I can see the message body in step 7 and 8.